# After drag-and-drop an image inside Canvas of HTML 5, how can I display it's ID? 

Tags: image, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am having 4 images inside Canvas in HTML5. When I drop the image somewhere in the Canvas, I want to display the name of the image inside my Canvas .
Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how can it be done?

The source code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/D4w0ThwR). KineticJS is used to handle the canvas.

Comment: We'll need a bit more details/sample. For example, how do you handle your drop? Are the image concerned the 4 images of the beginning of your question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D4w0ThwR please go through this buddy @Py.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used KineticJS before, but from what I read in the [doc](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-events-tutorial/) :

> To detect drag and drop events with KineticJS, we can use the on() method to detect dragstart , dragmove, or dragend events. The on() method requires an event type and a function to be executed when the event occurs.

It'll end up beign something like this

```
rajiniGroup.on('dragend', function(evt) {
   // add your text somewhere using a shape text
};
```

Shape text are detailed in the [doc](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/) as well.